Is playing with a football team that has a cross in their logo in video game(Fifa) haram or kufr?
For example playing with a team like Real Madrid, has a cross on the badge(logo). Would choosing to play with this team, make the player sinful or kufr? Even-though the video characters are the ones wearing it?

not my brother. the cross hasn't any weight toward the religion. there is nothing advising you to distance yourself from cross or any other religious symbol in quran, hadith, and sunnah. remember my brother that islam is based on logic.

Please refrain from posting self-arrived conclusions and interpretations and only post accepted, academic references for your answers. Please read: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

So is it haram or not?

it is not haram
